# Node add custom fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'd like to add some custom fields.

A new content type called 'slider' with only text filed and a body summary.

I follow a [official example](http://drupal.org/project/examples):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info().
 */
function slider_node_info(){
  return array(
    'slider' => array(
      'name' => t('Slider'),
      'description' => t('Add cool animation sliders'),
      'base' => 'slider',
      'title_label' => t('Slider Title')
      ),
  );
}


/**
 * Implements hook_node_type_insert().
 */
function slider_node_type_insert($content_type){
  dpm('xxx');
  if($content_type->type == 'slider'){
    $body_instance = node_add_body_field($content_type, t('Slider Content'));


    field_update_instance($body_instance);
  }
}


/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function slider_form($node, $form_state){
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

when i done it,i can't see the body summary , but the example has it. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom fields is easy with the [CCK Module](http://drupal.org/project/cck), just edit you content type and add fields.

If you are interested in using the [Flexslider module](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider), this [tutorial](http://coldfrontlabs.ca/blog/creating-responsive-image-slider-galleries-adaptive-images-drupal-7) has a great walkthrough on setting up what you are trying to do.

If you are interested in using the [Views Slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow), check out this [tutorial](http://maestric.com/doc/drupal7/views_slideshow_tutorial).

Comment: just as a note, this thread is tagged with Drupal 7, CCK is part of Core in D7, you dont need to install the module.